# POST Large files to RESTFUL WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-rest

I am using a WCF Restful service to upload some large pdf documents to server.
The code that I have written works fine for images upto 5mbs.But when I am sending images for than 5, I am getting error from server.The error will be sometimes a internal server error, or operation timeout or Entity too large.
**I have googled and also included all the changes in different fixes in stackoverflow and in other sites still its not working**.Somebody please help me in solving.I have included all the below changes in web.config file:-

```
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="4800"/>


 <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>

  <binding name="webBinding" transferMode="Streamed"
             closeTimeout="00:04:00" openTimeout="00:04:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:04:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
                         maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                         maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                         maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>



  <system.webServer>    
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"></requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

```
  <service name="SunTrust.CMF.SupportService.V1.SupportService">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="SunTrust.CMF.SupportService.V1.ISupportService"/>
  </service>
```

Even with all these changes its not working.

Comment: What specifically is the server error you get ? a 500 ? a 404.13 (content length too large,  see http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00696/0/Increasing-maximum-allowed-size-for-uploads-on-IIS7.html for how to affect this) ? Have you used WCF Logging (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx) and ServiceTraceViewer to look at the detailed error message ?

Comment: I am getting 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Ok, then the next thing you need to do it use the WCF logging to see whats behind the generic 500 error.